# Configuring GWT to return full exceptions to client

Tags: java, exception, gwt

When an uncaught exception occurs on the server, the client has the onFailure() method called on the async callback for the service call. He only gets StatusCodeExceptions, which provide little information. I would like to get the actual exception that occurred on the server with its stack trace. Is this possible in GWT?

In my service interface, I added 'throws Exception' to the methods where I want the exception details from the server. This permits me to get the Exception message that occurred on the server, but its stack trace still stops at the client.

I understand that this is not good practice for a production environment, but I would like to enable this for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a three step process.

1. Set the uncaught exception Handler. In the onModuleLoad() method should be fine.

   `GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());`
2. Create a class that will implement the GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler interface and will parse the Throwable.

   ```
   public static class ExceptionHandler implements GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
   @Override
   public void onUncaughtException(final Throwable e) {
       if (e instanceof UmbrellaException) {
           final UmbrellaException umb = (UmbrellaException) e;
           String errMsg = "";
           for (Throwable t : umb.getCauses()) {
               errMsg += t.getMessage() + "\n";
               for (StackTraceElement element : t.getStackTrace()) {
                   errMsg += element.getClassName() + "(" + element.getMethodName() + ":"
                           + element.getLineNumber() + ")\n";
               }
               /* errMsg String contains full stack trace */
           }

       }
   }
   ```

   }
3. Call the ExceltionHandler and pass in the Throwable that came in the onFailure maithod()

   `new ExceptionHandler().onUncaughtException(caught);`

If any exception occurs on the server simply throw the exception object to the client (from the RPC servlet)

Comment: So, I thought that the GWT uncaught exception handlers was for uncaught exceptions that originate from the client side. I didn't think this had to do with exceptions from the server. Any exceptions that occur on the server get processed in my onFailure() methods

Comment: Oh, I think this related question is what I need to do. I use an Uncaught exception handler as you suggest, but the handler lives on the server side. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324026/how-do-i-get-the-server-side-exception-message-with-gwt